# Maven warn or fail goal when resource filtering cannot find a property

Tags: maven

I am starting to work on a poorly documented Maven project. I have set up my profile for the project but I may or may not be missing property definitions that used during resource filtering. By default, if a property is not defined in a filtered file, the variable name is left in the copied resource and Maven continues silently.

Is there a way to force Maven to fast-fail in this case?

As a minimal example, take this pom,

```
     <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
      <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <name>my-app</name>
     <build>
      <resources>
       <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
       </resource>
      </resources>
     </build>
     <profiles>
      <profile>
       <id>production</id>
       <properties>
        <foo>Craig</foo>
       </properties>
      </profile>
     </profiles>
    </project>
```

And have a resource to filter:

```
 echo 'Hello, my name is ${foo}!' > src/main/resources/test
```

Then running `mvn clean install -Pproduction` produces a file that says `Hello, my name is Craig!` while running `mvn clean install` produces a file that says `Hello, my name is ${foo}!`.

So my question is; how do I force Maven to fail in the second case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, the Apache Maven Enforcer Plugin is your friend, especially the [RequireProperty](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireProperty.html) Rule

Comment: Does this require a new rule to be added every time a new property is added to the project?

Comment: No, only if that property is required. I would advice to go for good default first if possible.

Answer (score 5):

JIRA issues exist for this feature in The Codehause database:

- [MRESOURCES-163](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRESOURCES-163) Filtering: check if there are any placeholders that were not substituted
- [MRESOURCES-162](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRESOURCES-162) Fail build if resource not fully filtered

You can log in and vote for them. Unfortunately the demand for this important safety net feature seems to be low ... strange.